# laravel image upload error

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, intervention

i'm using intervention package to upload images with laravel and all things are fine from creating to saving image but the problem in the image column in database it stores this name with path

/private/var/folders/18/0w78rt691m99y_kv8xln4n0c0000gn/T/phpFkP3Gh

this is my code:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
  \Image::make($image)->save($location);
 }
```

and this is the image name stored in images file 1503847676.jpg

please help me to find, where is the problem?

this is my whole method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        // Validating fields requests
        $this->validate($request, [

            'title'     =>  'required|min:6',
            'subtitle'  =>  'required|min:6',
            'slug'      =>  'required',
            'body'      =>  'required',
            'image'     =>  'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
           $image = $request->file('image');
           $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
           \Image::make($image)->save($location);
        }

        //find target post
        $post = Post::find($id);

        //create upadeted data from inputs fields
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $post->image = $filename;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->image = $request->image;
        $post->status = $request->status;
        $post->body = $request->body;

        //save the new data to database
        $post->save();
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);

        return redirect('/admin/post');


    }
```

Comment: Show us ur whole `store()` method code

Comment: i wrote my full update method bro.

Comment: i solved it i was repeating $post->image twice

Comment: Ok. I've changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Intervention` package for simple image upload w/o any modifications like resize etc. Try this

```
if( $request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $location = public_path(). '/images/';
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move($location, $filename);

}
//find target post
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->image = $filename;

//remaining code
$post->save();
```

Comment: I used intervention because i faced the same problem with laravel upload file but no solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you use Intervention image

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);
$post->image = 'images/' . $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error like yours, I solved it by using the following:

```
$file = Input::file('image');
$image->move($location, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```